# Submit form without input field.

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to submit a `form` (or a request) to do some tasks. The `form` doesn't have input field except a `submit` button.

I know it's kinda strange but I want to submit the form and get the data by using only php.

Is that possible?

My codes

```
if($_GET['submitImage']){

   //do the stff I want......

}

<form id='formSubmitImage' name='submitImage' method='get' action='cm_ct_generate_preview.html'>
<?php
        echo "<table>";
          echo "<th>ID</th>";
          echo "<th>Type</th>";
          echo "<th>Name</th>";
          echo "<th>Image</th>";
          foreach($tests as $test){
              echo '<tr>';
                  echo '<td>';
                  echo $test['ID'];
                  echo '</td>';

                  echo '<td>';
                  echo $test['Type'];
                  echo '</td>';

                  echo '<td>';
                  echo $test['Name'];
                  echo '</td>';

                  echo '<td>';
                  echo $test['FileName'];
                  echo '</td>';
              echo '</tr>';
          }
          echo "</table>";
          echo "<input type='submit' value='Set Images'></input><br>";
?>
</form>
```

Are there any alternative way to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: IMHO, this smells bad. You should use the <a> tag do command actions in your application and forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
echo "<input type='submit' value='Set Images'></input><br>";
```

Why not:

```
echo "<button type='submit'>Set Images</button><br>";
```

Comment: yes but how do i verify if the user submit the form. I tried if($_GET['submitImage']) but it doesn't work.

Comment: change `method` attribute to `POST`, and then, in PHP: `if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `GET` parameter to the end of your `action` URL (in your case it would then be something like `cm_ct_generate_preview.html?submitImage=1` or you can add a hidden input field in the form and check if that is submitted, for example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="submitImage" value="1" />
```

As your form method is already set to `GET` it should be sent as a `GET` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If the user needs to activate it, let them just press the submit button. However if you want to do it automatically, you will need to use a little javascript. To send the data with it, you can just specify your inputs like this:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$test['ID'].'">';
```

the input fields will not appear but the data will be send like with an input field.

Comment: I don't need the hidden data. I just want to be able to submit the form without sending any input field data.

Comment: then you will need javascript to do the job.